# Way to bind ALT-F4 to exit in Bash (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows)

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Really simple question. I know I can exit bash with "exit", CTRL-D, etc, and yes I know I'm using a Linux (sub)system, but when I'm on windows ALT-F4 is second nature. Naturally, I'm on windows when using WSL. I've managed to get it to exit when I type "`" (backtick) persistently via bashrc with a `` bind -x '"`":"exit"' ``.
I can also get it to work per session with ALT-F4 by getting the keymap for ALT-F4 via CTRL-V, ALT-F4, (something like ^[[1;3S) and binding that to exit, but again, only for that session.

but if I use that same bind that exits per-session in my .bashrc and reload, it does not work, spitting out text (generally ;3S) instead. I know it's a trivial problem, I'd appreciate the help anyway.
Thanks

Comment: You may need to put it in `.inputrc` instead of `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consulted a friend, found answer. ";3S" was added on to the end of the keybind, though neither of us are sure why.
Regardless, adding `bind -x '"\e[1":"exit"'` to .bashrc or .bash_aliases (assuming it exists), will do the trick. it only works from bash, (i.e., if you're in VIM or whatever, it wont exit), but it's not a text replace like standard bind, so it can be used when the line isn't empty.

Obligatory Disclaimer for those in the future who may want to replicate this: Every distro is different, so your key combo may be different. find it, update the command with your key combo, and viola.